# Errors when installing php 7.0 package

Tags: php7

When I execute:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mhash php7.0-openssl
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-mhash
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-mhash'
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-openssl
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-openssl'
```

any suggestion? please

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to actually check for the packages first.

```
sudo apt-cache search php7.0- |more
```

---

## mhash

```
apt-cache search php7.0 | more
libapache2-mod-php7.0 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
php-all-dev - package depending on all supported PHP development packages
php7.0 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
php7.0-cgi - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
php7.0-cli - command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
php7.0-common - documentation, examples and common module for PHP
php7.0-curl - CURL module for PHP
php7.0-dev - Files for PHP7.0 module development
php7.0-gd - GD module for PHP
php7.0-gmp - GMP module for PHP
php7.0-json - JSON module for PHP
php7.0-ldap - LDAP module for PHP
php7.0-mysql - MySQL module for PHP
php7.0-odbc - ODBC module for PHP
php7.0-opcache - Zend OpCache module for PHP
php7.0-pgsql - PostgreSQL module for PHP
php7.0-pspell - pspell module for PHP
php7.0-readline - readline module for PHP
php7.0-recode - recode module for PHP
php7.0-snmp - SNMP module for PHP
php7.0-sqlite3 - SQLite3 module for PHP
php7.0-tidy - tidy module for PHP
php7.0-xml - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
php7.0-xmlrpc - XMLRPC-EPI module for PHP
libphp7.0-embed - HTML-embedded scripting language (Embedded SAPI library)
php7.0-bcmath - Bcmath module for PHP
php7.0-bz2 - bzip2 module for PHP
php7.0-enchant - Enchant module for PHP
php7.0-fpm - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
php7.0-imap - IMAP module for PHP
php7.0-interbase - Interbase module for PHP
php7.0-intl - Internationalisation module for PHP
php7.0-mbstring - MBSTRING module for PHP
php7.0-mcrypt - libmcrypt module for PHP
php7.0-phpdbg - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (PHPDBG binary)
php7.0-soap - SOAP module for PHP
php7.0-sybase - Sybase module for PHP
php7.0-xsl - XSL module for PHP (dummy)
php7.0-zip - Zip module for PHP
php7.0-dba - DBA module for PHP
```

As you can probably see in the list there is no openssl or mhash. Thus you can safely assume they are installed by default or does not exist for that version of php.

And according to this https://github.com/roots/trellis/issues/501 Php7.0 doesn't come with mhash but you might use it following php guidelines : http://php.net/manual/en/mhash.requirements.php

---

## OPENSSL

Comes installed under libapache2-mod-php7.0

```
  sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

To check it out you'll have to build a phpinfo() and search for openssl.